# node.js, express.js - What is the easiest way to serve a single static file?

Tags: node.js, express

I have already seen and made use of:

```
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
```

I do not wish to serve all files from the root directory, only a single file, 'ipad.htm'. What is the best way to do this with the minimum amount of code, using express.js?

Answer (score 133):

`res.sendFile(path_to_file);` is all you need; it will automatically set the correct headers and transfer the file (it internally uses the same code as `express.static`).

In express versions less than 4, use `sendfile` instead of `sendFile`.

Comment: I was getting 403s from this. I had to do `res.sendfile(relativePath, {root: theDirectory})`

Comment: if your folder is outside the one of the running JS file, I would add some detail to @kumar303 comment: you cannot put "../" in relativePath, but you can add it in theDirectory. res.sendfile(pic.png, {root: __dirname+"../../../images/"})

Comment: Is this with `app.get('css', function (req, res) { ... })`?

Comment: I found it useful to operate relative to the project root like this: path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename), '/relative/to/project/root/file.html')

Comment: In Express 4.x, it looks like all-lowercase `sendfile` is deprecated in favor of `sendFile` with a capital F. What worked for me, using `uuid.js` as my example, is `app.get('js/uuid.js', function(req, res) { res.sendFile('uuid.js', {root: 'node_modules/node-uuid'}); });`

Comment: The callback needs to be used, as shown [in the documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendFile), lest there be an error.

Comment: Express JS static is so confusing. I found it better not to use it and serve file directly as suggested by Tamlyn.

Comment: But how do I reference the static file elsewhere in my code?

Comment: For sending a file relative to the project directory, `res.sendfile(relativePath, {root: '.'})` works, at least with current versions, with no need to use `__dirname` etc.

Answer (score 17):

```
app.use("/css/myfile.css", express.static(__dirname + '/css/myfile.css'));
```

Comment: `app.use("/", express.static(__dirname + "/index.html"))` gives a 404 for me. `app.use("/", express.static(__dirname))` works.

Comment: that is strange, it does work for me. I have app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/wwwroot/index.html')); I think that the order in which they app.use calls appear does make a difference. So make sure you are not mapping it to somewhere else first that is giving the 404.

Comment: I get some weird 303 behavior that directs to the path plus a slash. Seems like static only is supposed to work on dirs.

Comment: Same with serve-static also.

Comment: I'm not using this for `index.html`, so can't comment on that -- but this solution works for me for the standard/filename-specified case. (express version: 4.17.1)

Answer (score 8):

If you precisely want to serve a single static file, you can use this syntax (example base on the original question, ipad.htm under root directory):

```
app.use('/ipad.htm', express.static(__dirname, {index: 'ipad.htm'}));
```

The default behaviour of express.static(*dir*) is that it will try to send an 'index.html' file from the required *dir*. The *index* option overrides this behaviour and lets you pick the intended file instead.

Comment: Only solution that fixed annoying favicon 404 requests. `app.use('/favicon.ico', express.static('img/base', {index: 'favicon.ico'}));`

Answer (score 5):

I published a small library for serving single static files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-static-file

`npm install connect-static-file`

`var staticFile = require('connect-static-file');
app.use('/ipad', staticFile(__dirname + '/ipad.html'));`

The main difference with express.static is that it does not care about the request url, it always serves that file if the route matches. It does not suddenly start serving an entire directory if you name your directory "ipad.html".

Comment: But how do I reference the static file elsewhere in my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "reference"? Do you want to use the contents somewhere else in your code? If so you can just use `require('fs').readFile(pathOfTheFile, (err, data) => {...})`

Answer (score 0):

Quick example building on JoWie's answer:

npm install connect-static-file

npm install express

```
var express = require('express');
var staticFile = require('connect-static-file');

var path = 'pathto/myfile.txt';
var options = {};
var uri = '/';
var app = express();
var port = 3000;

app.use(uri, staticFile(path, options));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Serving ${path} on localhost:${port}${uri}`));
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
```

Comment: You'd need to explicitly write out at least the `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers beforehand.