# serveStatic() unable to locate a file

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js, and I am trying to use the serveStatic function to locate a specific file.

When I specify the exact path in the argument it doesn't work. However it works  only  when I specify the directory only , and name the file index.html inside that directory.

Any idea on how I can use to it locate a specific file? Any help would be really appreciated from you guys thanks!

Below is my code

```
    var connect = require('connect'),
        http = require('http'),
        serveStatic = require('serve-static');




    var app = connect();


   // app.use(serveStatic('public')); Works 


    app.use(serveStatic('public/test.html'));// doesn't work 
    app.use(function(req, res){


    });

    http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. How do you expect `app.use(serveStatic('public/test.html'));` to work?

Comment: Are you trying to serve a single file (just one file, nothing more)?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I am trying to have that file serve as the response. Its just a single file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js, express.js - What is the easiest way to serve a single static file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473607/node-js-express-js-what-is-the-easiest-way-to-serve-a-single-static-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serve-static` is meant to serve a whole directory (with all sub-directories, if any). You can't use it to serve just one single file.

What you could do with `serve-static` is to [set a default file to be sent when user requests a root of your directory](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#index) (by default it's an `index.html` file):

```
app.use(serveStatic('public', {index: 'test.html'}));
```

But if you really want to send just a single file, then is's better to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11478939/1202461):

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('test.html', {
    root: __dirname + '/public/'
  });
});
```

Though, the best possible solution is to read this file once and cache it. In this case there will be no need to access your storage device each time somebody is requesting this file:

```
var html_data = require('fs').readFileSync('./public/test.html');

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.send(html_data);
});
```

Comment: @LenoidBeschastny.   Ahh. I understand now. Thank you so much for making that clear.